# jQuery: How can I select multiple elements from one path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm curious if there is a way to condense this:

`$('foo input:checkbox, foo input:radio');`

---

I tried the following but no luck:

- ```
  $('foo input[type="checkbox",type="radio"]');
  ```

  This blindly doesn't work (prob bad syntax)
- ```
   $('foo input[type="checkbox"][type="radio"]');
  ```

  I think this would select all inputs that are both radio ***and*** checkbox, which won't ever be the case.

---

**Edit:**
*I changed `fooElement` to `foo` toi simplify the example*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]', $('fooelement'))
```

Or

```
$('[type="checkbox"], [type="radio"]', $('fooelement input'))
```

Or

```
$(':checkbox, :radio', $('fooelement input'))
```

Remember jQuery offers the abiltiy to specify a context to search in.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: @John: I knew that and forgot about it, that might be one fix :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('fooElement input').filter(":checkbox, :radio");
```

Comment: That is a little less cluttered, +1.  I'm curious if there's any more overhead/looping involved.

Comment: This is very simple. It will get all the elements by tag(`input`) first and then just `filter` by type.

Comment: Shankar, I understand what is happening.  I'm curious about the underlying overhead.  Are there two different for loops, vs one?

Comment: Wow I haven't seen this question in years -- if anyone else is coming along, I think I did some testing a year or so ago on jsperf and found `.filter()` to take unnecessarily longer

Answer (score 1):

`$('fooElement').find(':checkbox,:radio');`

Comment: +1 for choosing my first instict, I'm curious if there is anymore overhead/looping involved especially compared to John's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('fooElement input[type="checkbox"]').add('fooElement [type="radio"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not really "condensed", per se, but:

```
$('fooElement input[type="checkbox"], fooElement input[type="radio"]');
```